# Disable "There are unresolved dependencies from..." message

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

How do we disable the "There are unresolved dependencies from..." message that comes up whenever there are unresolved dependencies?

[image]

I would rather not be told this.

Comment: I assume this is from an extension - you should figure out which extension it is and file an issue with them.

Comment: Indeed, it is part of the C# (ms-vscode.sharp) plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In settings.json, add the following:

```
{
    "csharp.suppressDotnetRestoreNotification":true
}
```

Requires [**version 1.5-beta6**](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.5-beta6) of C# for Visual Studio Code.

Here is how to open the settings.json

[image]